# How to stop access trying to save record when you exit

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a form that isn't for adding or deleting , just checking if a record is in the database. Every time I try to close the form access try's to save the record to the database and then throws an error because there is already a record of the same values in the database.

How do I stop access from trying to save the record? I have tried Me.Dirty = false and Call Me.Undo in the onClose event. But none of these seem to work , any other ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Allow Additions`, `Allow Deletions`, and `Allow Edits` properties of the form to be `False`?

Comment: I had tried this yes and it hadn't work, I tried it again now and it has work I had set data Entry to true on my first attempt, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments above, adjusting the properties of the form to make it "read-only" (e.g., `Data Entry`, `Allow Additions`, `Allow Deletions`, and `Allow Edits` all set to `False`) solved the problem.